# Graph works fine in Jupyter notebook but not pycharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

Trying to create a visualization within python and while it works on jupyter notebook I'm unable to get the output I want within an actual IDE. Has this happen to anyone else? Code is exact same in both. And the jupyter runs in 1 cell (literally just copy and pasted).

**PyCharm:**

[image: PyCharm]

**Jupyter:**

[image: Jupyter]

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt #also tried import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import date, timedelta


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 7))
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/covid-19/main/data/countries-aggregated.csv',
                     parse_dates=['Date'])
yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
today_df = df[df['Date'] == yesterday]
top_10 = today_df.sort_values(['Confirmed'], ascending=False)[:10]
top_10.loc['rest-of-world'] = today_df.sort_values(['Confirmed'], ascending=False)[10:].sum()
top_10.loc['rest-of-world', 'Country'] = 'Rest of World'
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.pie(top_10['Confirmed'], labels=top_10['Country'], autopct='%1.1f%%')
ax.title.set_text('Hardest Hit Countries Worldwide')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: `IDE` is only tool to develope code - after developing you run code without `IDE` - so more important is if it can run directly in console/terminal `python script.py`. And maybe when you will run it in console then it will display some error mesage which can help you to see problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested code without `IDE` and it gives me the same wrong plot.

It also displays that it needs `normalize=True` in `ax.pie()` so I added it.

But it still didn't resolve main problem.

If you would use `print()` to see values in  variables then probably you could see empty `today_df` and it makes wrong plot.

First you forgot to assing `yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

```
 yesterday = yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

But most weird problem was my time zone. I live in place where `yesterday` gives date which doesn't exist yet in `CSV` and I had to use `timedelta(days=2)` (day before yesterday) to get some data and see plot.
Maybe after few hours they will update data in `CSV` and `timedelta(days=1)` will work for few hour - and later it will gives again  have the same problem, etc.

Better use

```
yesterday = max(df['Date'])
```

to get the newest data.

---

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from datetime import date, timedelta

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/covid-19/main/data/countries-aggregated.csv'

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 7))
df = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=['Date'])

#yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(days=2)
#yesterday = yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

yesterday = max(df['Date'])

print('yesterday:', yesterday)

today_df = df[df['Date'] == yesterday]

print(today_df)

top_10 = today_df.sort_values(['Confirmed'], ascending=False)[:10]
top_10.loc['rest-of-world'] = today_df.sort_values(['Confirmed'], ascending=False)[10:].sum()
top_10.loc['rest-of-world', 'Country'] = 'Rest of World'
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.pie(top_10['Confirmed'], labels=top_10['Country'], autopct='%1.1f%%', normalize=True)

ax.title.set_text('Hardest Hit Countries Worldwide')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```